# Ghostscript not silent print pdf on HP printer

Tags: api, printing, ghostscript

This code slient print on other printers,but on `HP LaserJet Pro M402-M403 PCL 6` will popup printer select dialog.

```
gsapi_init_with_args(ptr, 12, new string[] {
                    "-empty",
                    "-dPrinted",
                    "-dBATCH",
                    "-dNOPAUSE",
                    "-dNOSAFER",
                    "-dNumCopies=1",
                    "-sDEVICE=mswinpr2",
                    "-dNOPROMPT",
                    "-dNoCancel",
                    "-sOutputFile="%printer%HP LaserJet Pro M402-M403 PCL 6",
                    "-f",
                    "D:\\report.pdf",
                });
```

I want to auto select hp printer when print.

Comment: yes, I rename to "HP", but no effect.

Comment: I use ghostscript dynamic library api invoke `gsapi_init_with_args` function, I think %% is unnecessary, now I first set the HP printer as the default printer, and I replaced `-sOutputFile=...` with `-QueryUser=3` to print using the default printer. Thank you for your reply. I'll take a look at the ghostscript source code in a few days to confirm the problem.